# Graph plotting in WPF (functionality)

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, plot

Please point me in right direction, I need to plot a graph in `C# WPF` with following functionality:

1. Plot Data points
2. Label plotted Data points with unique ids
3. Link the joints with each other by using arrow directed lines
4. Able to select any of the Data point by moving mouse cursor on the data point.So i can use the selected data point id.

Comment: I am currently using Dynamic Data Display library and I have implemented data points Plotting and joined those plotted data points without arrow directed lines but cannot find how to labelled them individually and how to select any data point by using mouse.and as i said cannot do arrows directed lines

Comment: best way is to implement yourself, if your requirement is not too complex.

Comment: I dont know about anyone else, but this question requires much more information/code before I could feel comfortable taking a stab at what your problem is.

Comment: actually i am asking to please suggest any good open source graph library which i can use to implement above said functionalities

Comment: You can try ZedGraph with WindowsFormsHost. I am using it in project at the moment and I am very satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 2):

Try OxyPlot and plots are quite nice and having a lot of useful features:
http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

check out the Silverlight and wpf chart controls which has graph chart

www.silverlightcontrols.com

Answer (score 0):

sam you can use chart control in wpf to plot points,where you can use point series of data.
For unique id you have to connect to database,when you put cursor on particular point it will show id,just go through chart control it will help you.

Comment: do you mean chart control in WPF ToolKit ?? if not please send me the link